# Python - Creating a list of intergers and using recursion to add them up

Tags: python, recursion, indexing

I am trying to create a program that takes a user integer input, creates a list and then
using recursion adds the list.  The problem is when I put in 6 it comes up with 15 and the
answer should be (0+1+2+3+4+5+6) = 21.  Why is the math wrong?  I think it must be somewhere in the indexing because if you leave off the 6 you do get 15.

```
#Program which accepts a number from the user
#take the numbers 0 to the number input 
#and gives a total of the numbers

def main():
#Get the number from the user to define upper end of range
    num = int(input('Enter a non-negative integer: '))

#Create the list of numbers
numbers = list(range(0,num, 1))

#Get the sum of the list of numbers
my_sum = range_sum(numbers, 0, - 1)

#Display the total
print('The sum of 0 to', num, 'is: ', my_sum)

def range_sum(num_list, start, end):
if start < end:
    return 0
else:
    return sum(num_list)
#call the main function
main()
```

Comment: You should fix the indentation. `list(range())` should be shortened to just using `range()`.

Comment: Also, `range(0,num, 1)` is just `range(num)`

Comment: look at the numbers in `numbers`. Is it really that what you expect, and then look into the docs of `range` to see why.

Comment: you are not using recursion to add the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tail recursion:

```
def range_sum(nums, sum=0):
    if not nums:
        return sum
    sum += nums.pop()
    return range_sum(nums, sum)
```

Comment: I changed my code as follows BUT it is still giving me a answer of 15 when I enter six when it should be giving me 21 
    #Get the number from the user to define upper end of range
  num = int(input('Enter a non-negative integer: '))
 
    #Create the list of numbers
 numbers = list(range(0,num, 1))
    #Get the sum of the list of numbers
 my_sum = range_sum(numbers)
    #Display the total
 print('The sum of 0 to', num, 'is: ', my_sum)
    def range_sum(num, sum=0):
        if not num:
            return sum
        sum += num.pop()
        return range_sum(num, sum)

Comment: @Maggi3339336 are you still using `range(n)` instead of `range(n+1)`? [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

Comment: Perhaps I am confused.  Where are you talking about range(n+1)

Comment: @Maggi3339336: `range(6)` -> [0,1,2,3,4,5], not [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]. Type it in your prompt and see what happens

Comment: Are you talking about this line? 
#Create the list of numbers
 numbers = list(range(0,num, +1))  I need to create a range of numbers that starts at 0 and goes up to the number the user enters, so I can't enter a list myself

Comment: @Maggi3339336: Yes I got it, just add 1 to the number entered by the user and you're fine: `numbers = list(range(int(input()) + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple function to implement either recursively:

```
def recursive(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    return n + recursive(n - 1)
```

or iteratively:

```
def iterative(n):
    return sum(range(n + 1)) # note n + 1 - range excludes the stop argument
```

which is equivalent to:

```
def iterative_longhand(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n + 1):
        total += i
    return total
```

or, if a list is a necessity:

```
def recursive_list_sum(nums):
    if nums:
        return nums[0] + recursive_list_sum(nums[1:])
    return 0

recursive_list_sum(list(range(n + 1)))
```

Your title says "using recursion", but none of your functions call themselves. You are using recursion neither to build the list nor to add up its contents. This function:

```
def range_sum(num_list, start, end):
    if start < end:
        return 0
    else:
        return sum(num_list)
```

called like:

```
range_sum(numbers, 0, - 1)
```

is just `sum(num_list)`, as `start > end`. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve - if it should be recursive, there should be a call to `range_sum` inside it.

Comment: As I said, I am asking the user to give me one number i.e. 6.  Then I need to create a list that is all the numbers up to and including 6. i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. The using some recursive method add all the numbers up and give the answer.

Comment: I have added a recursive list version

Answer (score 0):

There is no recursive call in the code. You are using the sum function, which comes defined in Python.